# debugging while uploading large file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, web-config

I've checked many threads about this but I'm not sure how to fix this:

When I try to upload a 33 mb file while debuggin, control directly falls into application_endrequest even when I've a breakpoint set to first line in application_beginrequest in my global.asax.cs. I can see the page in non-postback case.

**My maxRequestEntityAllowed is set to 400000, and in web.config I got**

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024000"/>
```

What else do I need to fix? I can upload a 25mb file btw.

platform: IIS7, Windows 7 64 bit, .NET framework 2.0, integrated pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it set in your Web.Config, which is fine if it's less than the IIS limit.  However, if the IIS limit is less than what you specify in the Web.Config, the smaller limit wins.  Did you check the IIS limit?

See [here](http://www.cyprich.com/2008/06/19/fixing-file-upload-size-limit-in-iis-7/) for details in fixing this in IIS7.

Comment: Thanks David!

For anybody interested, this did the trick on top of maxRequestEntityAllowed & maxRequestLength,
<system.webServer>
<security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security></system.webServer>